# Is there a database of steam user ID's?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Is there a database of steam user ID's? If not, could I make a database of some user ID's by using GetFriendList and then use GetFriendList on each user of that list and so on?

Comment: Of course. If you believe in "six degrees of separation" this should work. But it's not that sure that it will work on Steam because most pages are private after the GDPR came in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no public database of steamids but you can create it by crawling people's friendlists.

The `GetFriendList (v0001)` method of Steam Web API returns the steamid of each friend of a public profile. Most profiles are now private but you will still get an average of ~20-30 new steamids in every request.

The Steam Web API has a limit of 100,000 requests per day. This is enough if you just want a lot of steamids, but you will need many days or many API keys to create a global database of steamids